# Upload image with Laravel 6

Tags: php, laravel, image-uploading, laravel-6

I'm trying to upload an image but when I submit the form nothing happens at all. I end up with an empty image folder and a `null` image field in the database. I already tried many potential solutions online up until this point.

**Controller**

```php
class ReportsController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * Only logged in users can access reports.
     */

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('auth');
    }

    public function index()
    {
        $reports = Report::with(['victim', 'lost_vehicle'])->get();
        return view('reports.index')->with('reports', $reports);
    }

    public function create()
    {
        return view('reports.create');
    }

    public function store(ReportRequest $request)
    {
        $userid = Auth::user()->id;
        request()->validate([
            // 'image' => 'required|image|mimes:jpeg,png,jpg,gif,svg',
        ]);
        $victim = Victim::create([
            'vic_name' => $request->input('name'),
            'vic_statment' => $request->input('statment'),
            'case_id' => uniqid(),
            'report_status' => $request->input('status'),
            'user_id' => $userid,
        ]);

        if ($files = $request->file('image')) {
            $carImage = time().'.'.$files->getClientOriginalExtension();
            $request->image->move(public_path('images'), $carImage);
            $victim->lost_vehicles()->create([
                'image' => $carImage,
            ]);
        }
        $victim->lost_vehicles()->create([
            'type' => $request->input('type'),
            'model' => $request->input('model'),
            'production_year' => $request->input('year'),
            'color' => $request->input('color'),
            'value' => $request->input('value'),
            'marks' => $request->input('marks'),
            'plate_number' => $request->input('plate'),
            'chassis_number' => $request->input('chassis'),
            'last_location' => $request->input('location'),
            'last_time_spotted' => $request->input('last_time_spotted'),
            'victim_id' => $victim->id,
        ]);

        return dd($victim);
    }
}
```

I set the form to accept files `{!! Form::open(['url'=>'reports'], array('files'=> true)) !!}`.

Comment: `Form::open` only takes 1 argument

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've got an issue with this part of your code:

```php
if ($files = $request->file('image')) {
    ...
    $victim->lost_vehicles()->create([
        'image' => $carImage,
    ]);
}
$victim->lost_vehicles()->create([
    ...
]);
```

You're correctly checking for the existence of `$request->file('image')`, but you're calling `$victim->lost_vehicles()->create()` twice. This is fine if `lost_vehicles` is a `hasMany()` relationship, but you'll end up with 2 records in the database, one with an image and no information, and another will all the information and no image. Consider refactoring:

```php
$image = null;
if ($files = $request->file('image')) {
    $carImage = time().'.'.$files->getClientOriginalExtension(); 
    $request->image->move(public_path('images'), $carImage);

    $image = $carImage;
}

$victim->lost_vehicles()->create([
    'type' => $request->input('type'),
    'model' => $request->input('model'),
    'production_year' => $request->input('year'),
    'color' => $request->input('color'),
    'value' => $request->input('value'),
    'marks' => $request->input('marks'),
    'plate_number' => $request->input('plate'),
    'chassis_number' => $request->input('chassis'),
    'last_location' => $request->input('location'),
    'last_time_spotted' => $request->input('last_time_spotted'),
    'victim_id' => $victim->id,
    'image' => $image
]);
```

What this does is sets `$image` to `null` initially, and then if your check passes, sets it to the string representing the uploaded image. Then, it is included in the `create()` method below, and you should have all data associated.

Aside from that, I haven't seen that method for uploading the image. I use:

```php
\Storage::disk("local")->putFileAs("images", $files, $carImage);
// Modified to fit your variable names
```

And also make sure you've called `php artisan storage:link` to correctly link `storage/app` to `public`.

Comment: i did exactly as you said and still the picture name doesn't get saved on the database and the file doesn't move to storage !

Comment: Hmm... Are you getting any errors? I don't think that would happen without some associated error (unable to move file due to permissions, invalid location, etc.)

Comment: not getting any errors at all, all the fields get inserted to the db except the image field

Comment: Ah, so that means that `if ($files = $request->file('image')) {` is failing. Can you do a `dd($request->file('image'));`? It should be an instance of `UploadedFile`.

Comment: it's returning null

Comment: There's the problem then :) What does your `Form::` element look like for the image uploader?

Comment: here it is `{!! Form::file('image', null, ['class'=>'form-control']) !!}`

Comment: this line `<input type="datetime-local" class="form-control" id="last_time_spotted" name="last_time_spotted">` looks like this but i don't think it might cause any problems

Comment: Nope, that line shouldn't be an issue. I don't see anything wrong with the `Form::file()` call, but I don't use `Form::` method personally. Does it generate the following HTML: `<input type="file" name="image" class="form-control"/>`? Also, does your `<form>` element have the `enctype="multipart/form-data"`? (You'll have to inspect your page from your browser to see the computed HTML)

Comment: the opening of the form element looks like this `{!! Form::open(['url'=>'reports'], array('files'=> true)) !!}` but still it doesn't have the `enctype="multipart/form-data"`

Comment: Hmm, I thought that's what the `'files' => true` entry would do. Should that be in the same array? `{!! Form::open(['url'=>'reports', 'files' => true]) !!}`?

Comment: `Form::open` only takes 1 argument